# Comparator in a Priority Queue: Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, heap, priority-queue

I'm new to Javascript and thus this question,
I understand arrow functions. However this syntax completely confuses me.
This is an implementation of a PriorityQueue which takes a function comparator as a callback, this is the syntax,

```
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor({ comparator = (a, b) => a - b, initialValues = [] } = {}) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
    this.data = initialValues;
    this.heapify();
  }
```

I don't understand what this line means,

```
{ comparator = (a, b) => a - b, initialValues = [] } = {}
```

The complete code is here, should you need it,
https://github.com/jeantimex/javascript-problems-and-solutions/blob/master/src/common/priority-queue.js

But can someone please help me understand that line of code. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: That syntax means "if `comparator` is not provided, use this default function `(a, b) => a - b`, and if no `initialValues` are provided, use an empty array"

Comment: @DacreDenny could you put it as a more deliberate answer with some examples. I'm new to JS.

Comment: sorry about that, looks like CertainPerformance has got this answer covered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor expects zero or one argument, which, if provided, should be an object.. If the argument is not provided, it defaults to an empty object. Then, it checks the (possibly empty) object for the properties `comparator` and `initialValues`. If those properties exist on the object, they are extracted into those variable names (`comparator` and `initialValues`) - otherwise, those variable names are assigned the default values, `(a, b) => a - b` for `comparator` and `[]` for `initialValues`.

Eg

```
new PriorityQueue()
```

results in a `PriorityQueue` with `.comparator` of `(a, b) => a - b` and `initialValues` of `[]`, whereas

```
new PriorityQueue({ comparator: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b) })
```

results in a `PriorityQueue` with `.comparator` of `(a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)` and `initialValues` of `[]`.

If properties other than `comparator` or `initialValues` are in the passed argument, they are ignored.

Written verbosely, without default parameters:

```
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(obj) {
    if (obj === undefined) {
      obj = {};
    }
    if (obj.comparator === undefined) {
      obj.comparator = (a, b) => a - b;
    }
    if (!obj.initialValues === undefined) {
      obj.initialValues = [];
    }

    // main constructor body starts here
    this.comparator = obj.comparator;
    this.data = obj.initialValues;
    this.heapify();
  }
```

Comment: FYI, `(a, b) => -(a < b) || +(a > b)` works as a substitute for both `(a, b) => a - b` and `(a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)` unless the string comparison actually requires the Intl support [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) has.

Comment: What does the trailing `={} `mean, sorry I know it might be a naive question.

Comment: @MelissaStewart That's the second sentence of the answer - if the argument is not provided, it defaults to an empty object.

Comment: @CertainPerformance is there a long hand way of writing this and if so, can you update your answer with that too, I'm really trying to learn the language and it isn't proving easy.

Comment: This is called "destructuring assignment", and this particular case is about object destructuring. @MelissaStewart, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment